# Fetched firestore data not displaying on first page load with React useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am trying to display data from a firestore database by pushing it to an array and mapping it. My goal is to have it display on the first page load, however, it only displays after I make changes to my code and I don't know why. My suspicion is that it has something to do with the dataArray.push() not waiting for the fetch to finish, but I'm not sure. I'll attach some images to show what I mean, I have tried fixing this but nothing works.

On first page load: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM6sU.png

After editing the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u43We.png

````
import '../css/ClassBox.css'

import { db } from '../Firebase/firebase'
import { doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

function ClassBox() {

  const [dataArray, setDataArray] = useState([])
  const [classesArray, setClassesArray] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
        var tempArray = []
        const userData = await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', localStorage.getItem('id')))
        tempArray.push(userData.data().classes)
        tempArray = tempArray.toString().replace(/\s*\,\s*/g, ",").trim().split(",")
        setClassesArray(tempArray)
    }
    const fetchClassData = async () => {
        for(let i=0; i<classesArray.length; i++) {
            let data = await getDoc(doc(db, 'classes', classesArray[i]))
            dataArray.push(data.data())
        }
        console.log(dataArray)
    }
    fetchUserData()
    .then(fetchClassData())
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='classBoxList'>
        {dataArray.map((classes) => (
            <div className='classBox'>
                <div className='classBoxContainer'>
                    <div kclassName='classBoxWrapper'>
                        <div className='statusContainer'>
                            <h3>CS 106</h3>
                            <h4 key={classes.status}>{classes.status}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className='classInfoContainer'>
                            <ul>
                                <li key={classes.classCRN}>CS 106 - {classes.classCRN}</li>
                                <li key={classes.instructorName}>{classes.instructorName}</li>
                                <li key={classes.building}>{classes.building}</li>
                                <li key={classes.instructionMethod}>{classes.instructionMethod}</li>
                                <li key={classes.takenSeats}>Seats: {classes.takenSeats}/{classes.totalSeats}</li>
                                <li key={classes.remainingSeats}>Remaining: {classes.remainingSeats}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default ClassBox ```
````

Comment: in first page load, your data is an empty array. so it is normal that your code renders no data. it takes a little time to fetch your data, so after fetch you need a re-render. in your useEffects dependency array add dataArray and classesArray. So whenever the values of these arrays changes, useEffect will re-render your page with updated data

Comment: also you can run functions with await instead of fetchUserData()
    .then(fetchClassData()).

Comment: I added dataArray and classesArray as dependencies and it triggered the useEffect multiple times and overflowed my data array like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZcYr.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, inside .then (next to fetchUserData), you wrote a function call rather than a callback. Change it to .then(() => callback()) or .then(callback).

Second, state changes inside useEffect loop reflects changes only after the next render. So even after calling setClassesArray inside fetchUserData, fetchClassData will be called with the previous value of classesArray.

Third, you can't push to dataArray directly, rather use setDataArray call only.

Try this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
        let tempArray = []
        const userData = await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', localStorage.getItem('id')))
        tempArray.push(userData.data().classes)
        tempArray = tempArray.toString().replace(/\s*\,\s*/g, ",").trim().split(",")
        setClassesArray(tempArray)
        return tempArray
    }
    const fetchClassData = async (newClassesArray) => {
        let tempArray = []
        for(let i=0; i<newClassesArray.length; i++) {
            let data = await getDoc(doc(db, 'classes', classesArray[i]))
            tempArray.push(data.data())
        }
        setDataArray(tempArray)
    }
    fetchUserData()
    .then((tempArray) => fetchClassData(tempArray))
  }, [])
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) also had to add classesArray as a dependency to the useEffect() and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly mutating the dataArray state variable using push. You should use setDataArray() instead.